# Custom SharePoint workflow action always returns error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I'm developing a custom workflow action for use in SharePoint Designer that will return a concatenated string from a list. It actually works fine internal to the action, but always returns an error.

> An error has occurred in Test workflow

Inside the ULS log there is a null pointer error, except I can't see where.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.SPUserCodeWorkflowActivity.ExecuteUserCode()
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.SPUserCodeWorkflowActivity.System.Workflow.ComponentModel.IActivityEventListener<System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutionStatusChangedEventArgs>.OnEvent(Object sender, ActivityExecutionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutorDelegateInfo`1.ActivityExecutorDelegateOperation.Run(IWorkflowCoreRuntime workflowCoreRuntime)
     at System.Workflow.Runtime.Scheduler.Run()
```

I'm stumped to why it returns an error at the end of the method. The method that is called here

```
public Hashtable ListColumnToString(SPUserCodeWorkflowContext context, string ListName, string ColumnName, string Delimiter)
{
    Hashtable results = new Hashtable();

    try
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(context.CurrentWebUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists[new Guid(ListName)];
                string output = string.Empty;

                foreach (SPItem item in list.Items)
                {
                    output += item[ColumnName].ToString() + Delimiter;
                }

                results["OutputString"] = output;

                SPWorkflow.CreateHistoryEvent(web,
                    context.WorkflowInstanceId,
                    0,
                    web.CurrentUser,
                    TimeSpan.Zero,
                    "Information",
                    output,
                    string.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        results["OutputString"] = string.Empty;
    }

    return results;
}
```

The workflow will correctly log the *output* value with what I expect, and at the point of the log command, the workflow action has completed the code block but the workflow still reports an error at this step.

[image]

I'm creating the workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010 and it only has one step and one has this custom action. If I add an additional action, it is never reached due to this error.

[image]

How do I get this workflow action to return success?

**Elements.xml** - in case it's relevant, here is the action XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <WorkflowActions>
    <Action Name="List Column to String"
            SandboxedFunction="true"
            Assembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
            ClassName="ListColumnToStringActivity"
            FunctionName="ListColumnToString"
            AppliesTo="all"
            Category="My Custom">
      <RuleDesigner Sentence="From %1 list, %2 column. Save to string %3 with %4 delimiter">
        <FieldBind Field="ListName" Id="1" Text="List name" DesignerType="ListNames" />
        <FieldBind Field="ColumnName" Id="2" Text="Column name" DesignerType="Text" />
        <FieldBind Field="OutputString" Id="3" Text="Output string" DesignerType="ParameterNames" />
        <FieldBind Field="Delimiter" Id="4" Text="Delimiter for columns" DesignerType="Text" />
      </RuleDesigner>
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter Name="__Context"
                   Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.WorkflowContext, Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions"
                   Direction="In"
                   DesignerType="Hide" />
        <Parameter Name="ListName"
                   Type="System.String, mscorelib"
                   Direction="In"
                   DesignerType="ListNames"
                   Description="Name of list" />
        <Parameter Name="ColumnName"
                   Type="System.String, mscorelib"
                   Direction="In"
                   DesignerType="TextBox"
                   Description="Name of column" />
        <Parameter Name="OutputString"
                   Type="System.String, mscorelib"
                   Direction="Out"
                   DesignerType="ParameterNames"
                   Description="Delimited string returned" />
        <Parameter Name="Delimiter"
                   Type="System.String, mscorelib"
                   Direction="In"
                   DesignerType="TextBox"
                   Description="Delimiter" />
      </Parameters>
    </Action>
  </WorkflowActions>
</Elements>
```

**Update**

After a lot of looking, I found three more entries in the ULS log when I execute the workflow. I'm not sure what to do to fix these, but it sounds like I'm missing an entire configuration file somewhere.

```
Solution Deployment : Looking for 'ReceiverAssembly' attribute in manifest root node for solution 'SharePoint.ListColumnToString.wsp'.   
Solution Deployment : Looking for 'ReceiverClass' attribute in manifest root node for solution 'SharePoint.ListColumnToString.wsp'.
Solution Deployment : Missing one or more of the following attributes from the root node in solution SharePoint.ListColumnToString.wsp: assembly '', type ''.
```

Comment: This might seem like a stupid quesiton but have you checked the ULS logs? If you cannot locate any problem then try using a custom tracer to insert some logging there to help you locate the entries. ULSViewer is a very good too to analyse logs. Good luck

Comment: I was wrong and found a null pointer reference in the ULS log, but it's very non-descript.

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace with us?

Comment: I've added it to the top of the question. It's not very helpful and happens after it logs the correct output to the workflow at the end of the function.

Comment: I've found some related log messages that I'm going to research, but I've added them to the end of the question